# Regex Expression for a URL Whitelist

Tags: regex

This has been driving me crazy.

I need to construct a single regex expression of a whitelist of urls to allow my site to link to.
They should be of the form:

```
*.microsoft.com/*
```

So the following urls are valid:

```
http://digital.microsoft.com/audio/somefile.wmv
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/pages/p1
```

And the following invalid:

```
http://badsite.microsoft.com.me
http://www.microsoft.com.me/runthis
```

I need a regex expression which will allow valid microsoft sites to be linked to, but block malicious sites which my submit links with the words microsoft.com in them.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer by @ruakh, I was able to tweak the expression to match my scenario:
I will mark his post as the answer.

Expression: `^([a-z|A-Z])+?://([^/]+[.])?(microsoft[.]com|MICROSOFT[.]COM)?(/.*)?$`

This expression correctly matches the following:

- `http://test.microsoft.com/?page=1` `http://msevents.microsoft.com`
- `https://myevents.microsoft.com/somesubsite/Event.aspx?EventID=56456&Culture=en-US`
- `mms://digital.microsoft.com/456/videos/23800_str.wmv`
- `http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9775098`
- `http://GO.MICROSOFT.COM/?linkid=9775098`

And correctly does not match the following:

- `http://me.microsoft.com.au`
- `http://microsoft.com.mysite.com`
- `http://microsoft.com.mysite.com/blah`
- `mms://microsoft.com.mysite.com`

Comment: Do you have a list of valid Microsoft ccSLD's (microsoft.com.au, microsoft.com.tr, etc)?

Comment: @Greg, I have searched this site extensively and have not found a post similar to mine. I used RegEx a long time ago and because of the time crunch wanted something I could plug in quick.

Comment: @Zeke for now, I would be happy with matching urls with *microsoft.com* in it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you've thought this out. How can a regex determine that `http://www.microsoft.com.me/runthis` is not a valid MS site while, presumably, `http://www.microsoft.com.au/runthis` is OK? They both match `*.microsoft.com.*/*`.

Comment: @Borodin I agree and have changed my question to just match on urls ending with the [*].microsoft.com/[*] domain

Comment: Your updated regex has too many question marks. This is a **huge** problem: your current regex will accept something like `http:///stackoverflow.com/`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a URL-parsing library, but since you say you need "a *single* regex expression" (emphasis mine), I take it that, for some externally-driven reason, you really need to do this in a regex? In that case, I'd probably write something like:

```
^(https?|mms)://([^/]+[.])?(?i:microsoft[.]com)(/.*)?$
```

Comment: The reason why I need to use RegEx is so that the filter can be modified independent of a release (the expression will be saved in a DB).

To clarify on the negative checks, my emphasis is really trying to ensure that the website url ends with microsoft.com rather explicitly check for extensions the end.

So I want to ensure that this is a valid url:
http://media.microsoft.com/assetid=1234
and stop this:
www.microsoft.com.fakesite.com/pageid=123

Thanks for the reply so far.

Comment: I tweaked your script above to remove the negative checks and so far it is looking good with: 
`^https?://([^/]+[.])?microsoft[.]com?(/.*)?$`

Oops spoke too soon, I also have urls of this type:
mms://digital.microsoft.com/events/videos/media.wmv

How can I allow all protocols (or should I even bother checking)?

Comment: Ok updated the main question with the final tweaked expression.

Comment: @ShailenSukul: Re: "The reason why I need to use RegEx is so that the filter can be modified independent of a release (the expression will be saved in a DB)": I see. In that case, I still recommend you use a URL-parsing library. It sounds like your only criterion will be the domain name; so you can use a URL-parsing library to obtain the domain name, and then compare *that* against a configurable regex. That's still a much less error-prone approach than matching the entire URL against a regex. (And you can, of course, have a separate configurable regex for other URL components, just in case.)

Comment: @ShailenSukul: I see that you've removed the bit about `.au`. I've updated my answer accordingly, and also to support `mms:` and `MICROSOFT.COM`. It may not be a good idea to support arbitrary protocols, because arbitrary protocols can launch arbitrary programs on the user's computer. (The programs and protocols must already be installed, so it's not like running arbitrary code, but still, it greatly increases the chances for exploitation.)

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. Do you have any good suggestions for a url parsing library?

Comment: @ShailenSukul: You haven't mentioned what language you're using. If you're using Java, try `java.net.URL`. If Perl, try `URI`. If C# (or elsewhere on .Net), try `System.GenericUriParser`. If PHP, try `parse_url`. In general, if you Google the name of the language you're working in, plus "URL" and "parser", you should find something within the top few hits, and it's very likely to be something that comes pre-packaged with the language.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more sophisticated regex: `^([a-z|A-Z])+?://([^/?#]+[.])?(microsoft[.]com|MICROSOFT[.]COM)?(/.*)?$`

if you also don't want to match:

```
http://go.something.com?go.microsoft.com
http://go.something.com?param=go.microsoft.com
http://go.something.com#go.microsoft.com
```